# How to pass a signal as function parameter?

Tags: c++, qt

So i am looking to make our own generic inherited checkbox class that will be able to take in some values in its constructor and pop out a widget that is fully connected to our model in the manner we need.

Currently we do something like this within our view

```
connect(checkboxWidget, &QCheckbox::Clicked, this, &VMyView::Signal);
```

Which emits the Signal from VMyView when the checkbox is clicked.

If i wanted to pass that signal as a parameter into my new inherited class to be hooked up in its own connect statement, how would I do so?

Research has shown me i can pass a const char* but i get compilation errors that the signal/slot do not match.

Example

```
CheckBox(View myView, const char* signal)
{
    connect(this, &QCheckBox::Clicked, myView, signal);
}
```

Returns an error that Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.  Ive also tried SIGNAL(signal) with the same result.

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: @eyllanesc It's perfectly fine to connect a signal to another signal.

Comment: @eyllanesc You can forward signals?  Thats all this does, is forward a signal that our controller hooks into.  I just need to understand how you would pass a signal as a parameter in a function.

Comment: This is not intended use of signals, so please don't do this. If whoever creates a `CheckBox` wants a signal raised whenever `CheckBox::Clicked()` is raised, then they can connect it themselves to their own signal as needed.

Comment: @user1024792 signal is a simple pointer-to-method. Why do you think that it should be passed via `const char *`. Strings are used as a workaround for old Qt4.

Answer (score 3):

The solution ended up being fairly simple in the end

Instead of using this from within my View

```
connect(pCheckbox, &QCheckBox::clicked, this, &MyView::Signal);
```

I use

```
    connect(this, &QCheckBox::clicked, View, signal);
```

Where signal and comes into my function via a function pointer

```
MyCheckBox::MyCheckBox(QWidget* parent, MyView* View, void(MyView::*signal)(bool))
```

The key takeaway is

```
void(MyView::*signal)(bool)
```

is equal too

```
&MyView::Signal
```

Comment: A couple of notes on this:
1. In this case the signal has 1 bool argument, evident from the solution but not obvious from the question.
2. If the receiving function wants to emit the signal, do the following: `auto signalMetaMethod = QMetaMethod::fromSignal(signal); signalMetaMethod.invoke(View, Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(bool, value));`

Answer (score 0):

I think the major issue here is that signals are not static member functions. Thus they require a pointer to an instance of the class to be called correctly. So you cannot just pass in things like `&VMyView::Signal`, as there's no corresponding `this` pointer attached to the function. (This is why most of the `QObject::connect()` overloads require an instance to the sender/receiver objects.)

One way to solve this is to create a function object, which contains both the member function pointer and the pointer to the object on which to call it. This can be passed to the `QObject::connect()` function just fine.

Here's an example:

```
// objects.h
#include <QtCore>

class Receiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Receiver( QObject *parent = nullptr)
            : QObject(parent)
        {
        }

        ~Receiver() { }

    signals:
        void sig(void);
};


class Sender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Sender(std::function<void(void)> &bound_signal, QObject *parent = nullptr) 
            : QObject(parent)
        {
            // automatically emit `Sender::sig` on a timer, for testing.
            timer = new QTimer(this);
            timer->setInterval(1000);
            QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Sender::sig);
            QObject::connect(this, &Sender::sig, bound_signal);
            timer->start();
        }

        ~Sender() { }

    signals:
        void sig(void);

    private:
        QTimer *timer;
};
```

And then a main function:

```
// main.cc
#include <QtCore>

#include "objects.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    Receiver receiver; // object to receive the signal

    // Bind the receiver's signal to the instance of the class
    std::function<void(void)> signal = std::bind(&Receiver::sig, &receiver);

    // Create a Sender, which will connect its own signal to the
    // given bound signal
    Sender sender(signal);

    QObject::connect(&receiver, &Receiver::sig,
            []() -> void { qDebug() << "received"; });
    return app.exec();
}
```

So, in your case, the `Receiver` and its signal would be replaced by `VMyView` and the signals you want to chain, and `Sender` would be the custom checkbox class you've implemented. Then in the constructor of the checkbox class, connect whatever signals you want to the given *bound* signals. You can also pass in a list of bound signals, e.g., `std::list<std::function<void(void)>> &bound_signals`.

I have to say, though, I'm not sure what this buys you. You'll need to write the connection logic *somewhere*, and I don't see why it needs to be in the constructor of the checkbox class. Wherever the checkbox and the `VMyView` class are created and used, that seems like a better place to put the connection code. It's more obvious, less convoluted, and there's better separation of concerns. The checkbox class shouldn't have to know or care what signals/slots its connected to. The application logic (i.e., where the objects are *used*) should define how the objects interact with one another.

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at this @bnaecker.  The goal is to reduce the clutter of the code if possible, our UI's are built programmatically and some contain 50+ of these widgets.  They are all just copy/pasted repeatedly one after another with a few things in their connections changed.  My hope was to create a class that did all this for us, so a function that builds a form would be 25 lines long instead of 250.  It also would help prevent errors on my part such as forgetting to change a signal when copy/pasting, and tracking those down can be a pain.

Comment: In regards to std::function<void(void)> signal = std::bind(&Receiver::sig, &receiver);.  In my case i would be wanting to do this within the instance of receiver itself...but if i try to pass in std::function<void(void)> signal = std::bind(&Receiver::sig, this); I get an error on std::invoke not having a matching overload...

Comment: @user1024792 I think you have the receiver/sender nomenclature backwards (or I do). When you construct your checkbox object, you want to pass the `VMyView` class and the signal in that you want to connect.

Comment: @user1024792 Also. If your goal is ultimately to simplify connecting a bunch of signals and slots, take a look at `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QObject *receiver)`. Given the `QMetaObject` of a `QObject` subclass named `sender`, it connects all the signals of `sender` to those of `receiver` that have a particular name format. Look at the docs for details on that format.